# Datepicker Get 1 Datepicker Value and Add 1 month to another Datepicker Value

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

Good day everyone.

As title, I need some help on the Datepicker, I'm newbie in this.

HTML:

```
<span class="input-group-addon">From</span>
<input type="text" class="datepicker" ID="datepicker1" />
<span class="input-group-addon">to</span>
<input type="text" class="datepicker" disabled="disabled" ID="datepicker2" />
```

Jquery

```
$('#datepicker1').datepicker().on('changeDate', function(ev) {
    var datepicker1 = new Date(ev.date);
    var datepicker2 = new Date();
    var day = ("0" + datepicker1.getDate()).slice(-2);
    var month = ("0" + (datepicker1.getMonth() + 2)).slice(-2);
    var datepicker2 = datepicker1.getFullYear()+"-"+(month)+"-"+(day) ;

    $('#datepicker2').val(datepicker1);
});
```

Problem:
1. IF 31st May, the datepicker2 value might be 31st June.
2. IF 25-12-2015 (dd-mm-yyyy), the datepicker2 value might be 25-13-2015 (dd-mm-yyyy)

How do I solve all of this :(

Answer (score 0):

Date/time programming is very difficult to get correct. There are so many caveats that unless you really enjoy date/time it's probably better to use a community solution. You may want to look into [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/). With it you can do

```js
moment().add(1, 'month');
```

It will handle most edge cases. In the case of `31 May`, it will be clamped to `30 June`. In the end of the month case, it will increase the year so `25 December 2015` will become `25 January 2016`